# Should links to Stack Exchange be considered as spam?

Tags: discussion, spam, hyperlinks, stack-exchange

I've just passed a test in the Triage.

It was easy. The question had all the characteristics of a bad question, and probably the test in the body of the question was added just to fill it.

I was sure it was a test, and I've marked the question as "Unclear" (there were already four votes for "Unclear"), among lots of alternatives (e.g. not related to coding, too broad, etc.).

What surprised me, after receiving confirmation that it was a test, was to read that the question had deleted as "Spam or Offensive" by "Community".

So, does Community, which is a member of Stack Exchange even if as a background process rather than a "real person", really consider the links to the sites of Stack Exchange as spam or, even offensive?

[image]

Comment: [https://aera51.stackexchange.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0-EF60neguk)

Comment: There are currently 88 deleted posts **from different, new accounts** that posted this content, since 2015. They are all copying sample text to try to meet minimum post length requirements, the links don’t actually lead elsewhere (the few exceptions that deviate from this are not hiding the links).

Comment: The text copied is the help text for the `Links` section of the in-editor toolbar help. Edit a post, click the question mark icon, then `Links` (first option).

Comment: Anyway, when a post has been flagged as *spam* or *rude* enough times it is automatically deleted by the system, which shows up as deleted by Community User. Community User doesn’t do any considering, community *members* did, through flagging.

Comment: Note that posts like "jekfbevfjekelegfjdo" are considered abusive too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters does that mean that if a sufficient number of users "fail the evaluation", the system simply ratifies and endorses their error? So then, in case, other users have to vote to reopen a post deleted by the System only because other user have flagged it ...?

Comment: @HansPassant how did you do that link thing above?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal Probably using `[descriptipn](actual link)` like `[https://google.com](https://www.bing.com/)` which gives us [https://google.com](https://www.bing.com/).

Comment: @user202729 What an abusive comment! Keep in mind that SO is a kind community, OK?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something you have to be on the lookout for is when people copy text. As Martijn noted, this user copied and pasted text from the help window. A similar problem happens when you see a 1 rep user posting a large section of text (searching for exact phrasing in Google often gives you the original), especially if that copied text contains any links at all. At the bare minimum plagiarized content needs mod flags (be detailed in explaining that the text was copied and link the source).

It's odd to see this red-flagged out (anything deleted by Community like this got enough spam/rude flags to delete). The usual action for stuff like this is closure, because the OP asked their entire question in the title and copied the text in this case to meet the minimum length requirements to post. That shouldn't be red flagged.

In general, SE/SO links aren't usually problematic. Questions like this should be closed. Answers that are only links like this should be flagged NAA/LQP (see [this Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer))

Comment: Links to Area 51, while within the Stack Exchange network, *are* pretty much always spam. That's someone spamming a proposed new Stack Exchange site. There's never going to be any relevant content there.

Comment: I've not run across many, so I'll defer to you on that one

Comment: @CodyGray: this post is not linking to a specific proposal, so it’s actually not spam. It’s just the help text for how Markdown links work. But yes, posts that link to *specific Area51 proposals* to promote them are spam.